# How to get good source code in Odoo to be able to use with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, odoo-13, source-code-protection

I'm trying to scrap my Odoo's inventory pages to be able to get all the pictures already in the DB, more than 9000, so i wrote a python script using selenium, it works like a charm but not on my Odoo's pages, the fact is that on Odoo's inventory pages i think the source code is genreated by AJAX or Js or something else. So when i try to scrap it i won't have the good source, so i cannot get the elements. I really don't want to have to download the 9000+ images and names by hand, if someone know how to capture the good source code could you please tell me ?

Python code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

import time

import urllib.request

import requests

import ssl


#Vars

base_url = "https://yourodoourlhere.com"

img_list=[]

symbols = [":","/","\"","?","<",">","\\","*","|"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

gcontext = ssl.SSLContext()


def Login():

    driver.get(base_url+"/web/login")

    login_form = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='login']")

    #print(login_form) #Test

    login_form.send_keys('your@odoologinhere.com')

    password_form = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='password']")

    password_form.send_keys('yourodoopasswordhere')

    log_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/form/div[3]/button")

    log_button.click()

    GetInventory()

    #print(driver.current_url) get current url

    #time.sleep(5) #specify the seconds TEST

    #driver.close()


def GetInventory():

    url=base_url+"/web#action=375&model=product.template&view_type=kanban&cids=1&menu_id=198"

    driver.get(url)

    CaptureImages()

   

def CaptureImages():


    url = driver.current_url

    driver.get(url)

    r=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")

    print(r)

   

    #get HTML src

    #r = requests.get(url,stream=True).text

   

    #BeautifulSoup

    soup = bs(r, 'html.parser')


    #find all images

    all_imgs = soup.find_all('img')


    #get images list

    for image in all_imgs:

        img_list.append(image['src'])

    print(img_list)


    #Loop to format images names and DL

    for img_url in img_list:

        img_name=img_url

        for symbol in symbols:

            if symbol in img_name:

                img_name=img_name.replace(symbol,"")

        #print(img_name)

        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(base_url+img_url, img_name)


    time.sleep(5) #specify the seconds TEST

    driver.close()





#CaptureImages()

Login()
```

from what i've found in chrome inspector, a page at https://myodoourl.com/web/dataset/search_read will have in "preview" section the following datas :

```
{jsonrpc: "2.0", id: 815011021, result: {length: 8120,…}}
id: 815011021
jsonrpc: "2.0"
result: {length: 8120,…}
length: 8120
records: [{id: 13968, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…},…]
0: {id: 13968, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
1: {id: 13965, product_variant_count: 2, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
2: {id: 13961, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
3: {id: 13442, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
4: {id: 13966, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
5: {id: 10820, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
6: {id: 10635, product_variant_count: 16, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
7: {id: 4348, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
8: {id: 12785, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
9: {id: 12797, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
10: {id: 12782, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
11: {id: 12781, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
12: {id: 10721, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
13: {id: 588, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "001 Misc",…}
14: {id: 13551, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
15: {id: 589, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "002 Misc",…}
16: {id: 590, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "003 Misc",…}
17: {id: 591, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "004 Misc",…}
18: {id: 950, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "005 Misc",…}
19: {id: 951, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "006 Misc",…}
20: {id: 10814, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
21: {id: 952, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "007 Misc",…}
22: {id: 953, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "008 Misc",…}
23: {id: 954, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false, name: "009 Misc",…}
24: {id: 11755, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
25: {id: 11756, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
26: {id: 11757, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
27: {id: 11744, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
28: {id: 4470, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
29: {id: 13623, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
30: {id: 5004, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
31: {id: 5134, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
32: {id: 5005, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
33: {id: 10158, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
34: {id: 10337, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
35: {id: 4712, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
36: {id: 11702, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
37: {id: 12504, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
38: {id: 10212, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
39: {id: 1134, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
40: {id: 1133, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
41: {id: 1132, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
42: {id: 1131, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
43: {id: 1130, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
44: {id: 1129, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
45: {id: 1128, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
46: {id: 1126, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
47: {id: 13331, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
48: {id: 1127, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
49: {id: 1124, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
50: {id: 1125, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
51: {id: 1123, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
52: {id: 979, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
53: {id: 978, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
54: {id: 1120, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
55: {id: 216, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
56: {id: 4045, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
57: {id: 1119, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
58: {id: 4044, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
59: {id: 10947, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
60: {id: 2369, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
61: {id: 2404, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
62: {id: 2405, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
63: {id: 1990, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
64: {id: 1559, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
65: {id: 2406, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
66: {id: 1558, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
67: {id: 1171, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
68: {id: 2930, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
69: {id: 5082, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
70: {id: 259, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
71: {id: 2551, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
72: {id: 5208, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
73: {id: 1170, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
74: {id: 11217, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
75: {id: 1138, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
76: {id: 969, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
77: {id: 1140, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
78: {id: 1999, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
79: {id: 403, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
```

and in each record there is :

```
0: {id: 13968, product_variant_count: 1, currency_id: [1, "EUR"], activity_state: false,…}
activity_state: false
currency_id: [1, "EUR"]
default_code: "12121212121212"
id: 13968
lst_price: 10
name: "\"Monkey's fist\" key ring Red"
product_variant_count: 1
qty_available: 0
type: "product"
uom_id: [1, "Units"]
```

Is there a way i could get the "id" and "name" fields from python ???

Comment: From what i found on the web i should send a POST request to the JSON so i can get the response's datas, but i don't know what data i must send in the request.... i found out the request URL is : /web/dataset/search_read but then i don't know what to do....

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i changed all my way of working on this problem and i came up to this solution that i share if someone needs :

requirements : Have a folder called "images" in same folder as the python script, have "odoorpc" module installed, i made it on python 3.9.4 so i don't know about 3.10...

```
import odoorpc
import ssl
import base64
from os import getcwd

#Vars
url = 'foobar.my.odoo.com' #without "https://"
db = 'mydbname'
username = 'my@odoousername.com'
password = 'myodoopassword'
symbols = [":","/","\"","?","<",">","\\","*","|","\t","\n","\r"]
img_dir=getcwd()+"//images//"

#Odoo connect
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context #For SSL connect
odoo = odoorpc.ODOO(url, protocol='jsonrpc+ssl', port=443)

def Login(): 

    print(odoo.version) #Test only
    
    # Login
    odoo.login(db, username, password)
    
    # Current user only for test
    user = odoo.env.user
    print(user.name)            # name of the user connected
    print(user.company_id.name) # the name of its company

    GetImages()

def GetImages():

    Prod = odoo.env['product.template']
    product_ids = Prod.search([])
    print(len(product_ids))
    for id_prod in product_ids:
        prod = Prod.browse(id_prod)
        img_b64 = prod.image_1920
        nom_prod = prod.name
        if img_b64 != False:
            imgdata = base64.b64decode(img_b64)
            for symbol in symbols:
                if symbol in nom_prod:
                    nom_prod=nom_prod.replace(symbol,"")
            filename = img_dir+nom_prod+".jpg"
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(imgdata)
            print(nom_prod+" img saved !")
        else:
            print(nom_prod+" has no image !")
Login()
```

Enjoy ;)